# XSLT transformation problem with dynamic attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

This is something that work:

```
$curRow[1]/@gridClose
```

but let say that I do not know the attribute name "gridclose". I will loop and get this attribute with the code.

With the debugger I can get the value "gridClose" with : $curCol/@id. So I am trying to get something like :

```
$curRow[1]/@{$curCol/@id}
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$curRow[1]/@*[ name() = $curCol/@id ]
```

Comment: This is the one I have choosen. Thank you, worked like I wanted +1